# Manual Mock Module Used By Components

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, mocking, jestjs

I have several components that make use of a single hook `useParams`. The jest docs suggest using `jest.mock` to replicate this hook. As you can imagine, writing this mock over the space of several files could get annoying and as such I am seeking to make use of manual mocks. Jest docs suggest I create a `__mocks__` directory adjacent to the file I'll be mocking - the file in this case being `react-router-dom.js` in `node_modules`. I have followed the directions of the docs and yet my tests are still failing because they cannot find `useParams` defined anywhere. 
An example:

**src/components/compOne.js** :

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

const Wrapper = styled.div``

export default function CompOne() {
    const { id = '123' } = useParams()
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <h2>{`ID: ${id}`}</h2>
        </Wrapper>
    )
}
```

**src/__tests__/compOne.js** :

```
import React from 'react'
import CompOne from '../components/compOne.js'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'

jest.mock('react-router-dom')

test('renders without crashing', () => {
    shallow(<CompOne />)
})
```

**root/__mocks__/react-router-dom.js** :

```
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => {
    useParams: () => ({
        id: 'MOCKED_VALUE',
    })
})
```

This is how the tests fail:

```
src/__tests__/compOne.js
  ● renders without crashing

    TypeError: (0 , _reactRouterDom.useParams) is not a function

       6 |
       7 | export default function CompOne() {
    >  8 |     const { id } = useParams()
         |                            ^
       9 |     return (
      10 |         <Wrapper>
      11 |             <h2>{`ID: ${id}`}</h2>

      at CompOne (src/components/navigator/pages/compOne.js:8:28)
      at ReactShallowRenderer.render (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer-shallow.development.js:829:32)
      at fn (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:645:55)
      at withSetStateAllowed (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-utils/src/Utils.js:99:18)
      at Object.render (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:645:20)
      at new ShallowWrapper (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:411:22)
      at shallow (node_modules/enzyme/src/shallow.js:10:10)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/compOne.js:8:5)
```

If you're wondering about the structure of the project, please refer to the typical structure of [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/folder-structure/) - with `myapp/` being `root/`

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup of your files is good. In your mock of `react-router-dom`, you’ll want to **export an object** that contains what you want the mock to have instead of calling `jest.mock`.

This is what you need to do in your `/__mocks__/react-router-dom.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  useParams: () => ({
    id: 'MOCKED_VALUE',
  })
}
```

Because you’re not mocking a core module of Node, you don’t need to call `jest.mock` at all. You can remove `jest.mock('react-router-dom')` from your test file.